# Is there any way to turn the hour '' 1-5-6 '' into '' 01-05-06 " ? (Just an example)

Tags: python, format, hour

Is there any way to turn the hour '' 1-5-6 '' into '' 01-05-06 "? I need the current time on that format.

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
data = date.today()
print(data)
agora = datetime.datetime.now()
print(agora)
hora = agora.hour
minuto = agora.minute
segundo = agora.second
print('{}-{}-{}'.format(hora, minuto, segundo))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `strftime`:

```
from datetime import datetime
agora = datetime.now()

print(agora.strftime('%H-%M-%S'))
```

Output:

```
09-59-58
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just use:

```
print(str(agora).split()[-1])
```

**Demo:**

```
import datetime
agora = datetime.datetime.now()
print(str(agora).split()[-1])
```

Output:

```
10:03:04.083606
```

If you care about the milliseconds + microseconds, use:

```
import datetime
agora = datetime.datetime.now()
print(str(agora).split()[-1].split('.')[0])
```

Output:

```
10:03:04
```

Answer (score 1):

To add leading zeros to a format string, you can use `:02d`.  The `0` specifies to use a leading zero:

```
print('{:02d}-{:02d}-{:02d}'.format(hora, minuto, segundo))
```

#### Test Code:

```
import datetime
from datetime import date

data = date.today()
print(data)
agora = datetime.datetime.now()
print(agora)
hora = agora.hour
minuto = agora.minute
segundo = agora.second
print('{:02d}-{:02d}-{:02d}'.format(hora, minuto, segundo))
```

#### Results:

```
2019-05-06
2019-05-06 19:06:06.459819
19-06-06
```